# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I am using Python 3.7.6 
And I am getting an error while verifying the local issuer certificate.

This is my code, essentially. I'm using requests to validate the system user and in return I am expecting an authorization token.

```
import requests
url = "https://localhost:5000/admin/validateSystemUser"
payload = "{\n\t\"name\": \"abc\",\n\t\"password\": \"def\"\n}"
headers = {
    'Content-Type': "application/json",
    'User-Agent': "PostmanRuntime/7.22.0",
    'Accept': "*/*",
    'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
    'Postman-Token': "0055fc8b-c5be-4dd7-a153-ae30d186b362,392cdbd4-feff-478a-89d1-54089e7ee0b8",
    'Host': "localhost:5000",
    'Accept-Encoding': "gzip, deflate, br",
    'Content-Length': "53",
    'Connection': "keep-alive",
    'cache-control': "no-cache"
    }
response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

The following error and exceptions are obtained as a result.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\P\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Users\P\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 343, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\P\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 839, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\P\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 344, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "C:\Users\P\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 345, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\P\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 423, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "C:\Users\P\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 870, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\P\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 1139, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\P\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Users\P\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Users\P\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 399, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /admin/validateSystemUser (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\P\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\P\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\P\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\P\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /admin/validateSystemUser (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)')))
```

How do I tackle this issue?

Comment: https://forum.eset.com/topic/22996-python-programs-not-functioning-because-of-ssltsl-protocol-filtering-ssl-certificate_verify_failed/